# Error de Eslint Preset en vueJS2

Tags: vue.js, eslint

Hola estoy declarando mi siguiente función computada y Slint me marca un error en sitaxis que no logro comprender mi metodo computado es el siguiente y enseguida anexo el error que me arroja esto.
Propiedad computada:

```
  columns() {
          return this.columnNamesFromCsv.map((columnName) => {
            return {
              name: columnName,
              label: columnName,
              align: 'center',
              sortable: true,
              field: (row) => row[columnName]
            };
          });
        }
```

Error:

```
 error    Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; parenthesize the returned value and move it immediately after the `=>`
```

Desde ya agradezco sus repuestas y opiniones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es el siguiente:

ESLint recomienda omitir "return" en la declaración de una *función flecha* cuando dicha función sólo tenga una sentencia. Es decir, en lugar de

```
const multiplica = (a,b) => {
  return a*b;
};
```

deberíamos usar

```
const multiplica = (a,b) => a*b;
```

Pero el problema es que si quieres devolver un objeto, no puedes transformar algo como

```
const multiplica = (a,b) => {
  return {
    factores: [a,b],
    resultado: a*b
  }
}
```

en esto:

```js
const multiplica = (a,b) => { factores: [a,b], resultado: a*b};
```

Porque tenemos una ambigüedad: las llaves son entendidas como el inicio del bloque y no como la declaración de un objeto, causando un error.

Pero existe una solución, y es la que te da el mensaje de error:

> Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; parenthesize the returned value and move it immediately after the `=>`

Traducción aproximada:

> Inesperado bloque (se refiere a las llaves) alrededor del cuerpo de la función flecha. Pon entre paréntesis (creo que parentesizar como verbo no existe) el valor devuelto y ponlo inmediatamente tras la `=>`

Es decir, algo como:

```js
const multiplica = (a,b) => ({ factores: [a,b], resultado: a*b});

console.log(multiplica(2,3));
```

En tu caso sería:

```
columns() {
  return this.columnNamesFromCsv.map(
    (columnName) => ({
      name: columnName,
      label: columnName,
      align: 'center',
      sortable: true,
      field: (row) => row[columnName]
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, gracias por toda la explicación me queda mucho más claro ahora, solo me di cuenta de un detalle al final te hizo falta cerrar un parentesis, muchisimas gracias empezaba a romperme la cabeza el error.

Comment: Tienes razón, arreglado